# Pass HashMap(String,Boolean) to nextActivity using Serializable method-Android

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, hashmap

I have a Hashmap which I want to pass to the next Activity, all answers show this method-:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("YourHashMap",hashMap);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

But it shows wrong 2nd argument, it needs Serializable not Map String,Boolean>

I even gave this the basic try-:

```
intent.putExtra("myMap",myMap);
```

**But it says it cannot resolve method**

Comment: I would suggest you pass an object instead of a `HashMap`. You might consider creating an object with a `HashMap` inside it. Make the object `Parcelable` and then pass it through intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tried by me and works-:
//Add Data

```
Intent ActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                Bundle bundles = new Bundle();
                bundles.putSerializable("myMap", (Serializable) myMap);
                ActivityIntent.putExtra("bundle",bundles);
```

//Extract Data

```
 Bundle  bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
        HashMap<String, Boolean> myMap = (HashMap<String, Boolean>) bundle.getSerializable("myMap");
        if(myMap.get(StringOfItemWhichIsTrue)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: I'll get back to you on that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 // pass HashMap from one Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);

                HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("var",true);
                Bundle bun = new Bundle();
                bun.putSerializable("map", map);
                intent.putExtra("bundle",bun);

                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.nothing);


                // get HashMap from another activity
                Bundle  bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
                if(bundle != null){
                    HashMap<String,Boolean> map = (HashMap<String, Boolean>) bundle.getSerializable("map");
                    if(map != null){
                        Log.e("bundle",map.get("var")+"");
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to transfer your values, object must be serializable, Change Param as per your requirement.

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
hashMap.put("key", "value");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("map", (Serializable)hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your `NextActivity` to get Data try this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<String, Boolean> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Boolean>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
    Log.v("HashMapTest", hashMap.get("key"));
```

Check for true

```
Boolean b= hashMap.get("key");

    if(b==true){
    //Your Toast Message
    }
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: As I have specified above, this basic way shows that the method is unresolved.

Comment: Try and then say which line shows you can not resloved

Comment: I tried again, it says "Cannot resolve method `putExtra(String,Map<String,Boolean>);`  "

Comment: Check Updated answer i added `(Serializable)`

Comment: My Bad!...I didn't add the "(Serializable)" before the Hashmap..It is not giving an error anymore..will accept your answer once it works..thanks!

Comment: Even after receiving no errors the data in the Hashmap has not been transferred.

Comment: What's the issue and how you trying to get data

Comment: The data has been added in the first activity, in the second activity after completing the steps you suggested I tried this to check if it had the data:
`if(myMap.get(StringWhichIHadAddedInMainActivityAlongWithBooleanTrue)){
//Make a toast
   }
`

Answer (score 0):

Try using singleton class to store the hashmap using setter method, and get it on the other activity using a getter method.